# Spring in Action, Fifth Edition

Tags: spring

I am planning to study spring framework. Is Spring in Action, Fifth Edition published in 2018 outdated for 2023? Is I still usable?

I find reading a much better resource to learn than watching videos. hence would really prefer a book over a udemy video course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i find reading books or docs much better than youtube or udemy and Yes I believe its still usable as it would cover most of the important topics , but if you have access to newer edition then why not check it out, but as i said 2018 edition is not too old to the point of unusable

Comment: ah I just realised theres a 6th edition!!!

Comment: yeahh, do give it a try